# Creating default object from empty value using laravel 6 and ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel

i have in an annonces table a multiple images, i want to update multiple images, but it gives me error:
`Creating default object from empty value` knowing that i tried to transform multipleimage to a given `json`.in the console it gives me the name of the images to select.

**AnnoncesController.php**

```
public function filesUpdate(Request $request,$id)
    {
        $Annonce=Annonce::find($id);
        $data = array();
         if($request->hasFile('images'))
         {
            foreach($request->file('images') as $file)
            {
                $path = $request->images->store('annonces');
                $Annonce->images = $path;
                array_push($data,$path);
            }
         }
        $Annonce->images = json_encode($data);
        $Annonce->save();
        return Redirect::to("annonces")
        ->withSuccess('Great! file has been successfully uploaded.');
    }
```

**web.php**

```
Route::post('annonces/filesUpdate','AnnoncesController@filesUpdate');
```

**details.blade.php**

```
    <form method="post" action="{{url('annonces/filesUpdate')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data" 
     class="dropzone" id="dropzone">
       <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
          {{ csrf_field() }}
    </form> 
 <script type="text/javascript">
               Dropzone.options.dropzone = 
            {
            maxFilesize: 12,
            renameFile: function(file) {
                var dt = new Date();
                var time = dt.getTime();
                var images = time+file.name
                console.log(time+file.name);
               return  images;
            },
            acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif",
            addRemoveLinks: true,
            timeout: 50000,
            success: function(file, response) 
            {
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(file, response)
            {
               return false;
            }
            };
   </script>
```

Comment: `find` can return `null`, you will have to check for this ... so `$Annonce` is `null` and you are trying to assign a property to it which creates a default object from empty value ... also you have no route parameter in that route so not sure what `$id` is supposed to be

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the id as route parameter in the form action so the $id value received in filesUptate method in controller will be null. You have to pass the $Annonce->id as route parameter via form action

```
//When you send this view as response from edit method you need to pass
//either $Annonce object or at least the $Annonce->id as $AnnonceId to the view
//If you pass the entire $Annonce object then append $Annonce->id as below
//to the form action or replace it with $AnnonceId if you are passing only
//$AnnonceId from the edit method of the controller

 <form 
    method="post" 
    action="{{url('annonces/filesUpdate/' . $Annonce->id)}}" 
    enctype="multipart/form-data"
    class="dropzone" id="dropzone"
>
       <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
          {{ csrf_field() }}
</form>
```

The error probably arises as you are trying to call store method on array.

Try the below

```php
public function filesUpdate(Request $request,$id)
{
    $Annonce=Annonce::findOrFail($id);
    $data = array();
    if($request->hasFile('images'))
    {
        foreach($request->file('images') as $file)
        {
            //Trying to call store on an array here
            //$request->images is not an instance of UploadedFile
            //$path = $request->images->store('annonces');

            //$file is an instance of UploadedFile
            //so you can call store method on it
            $data[] = $file->store('annonces');            
            
        }
    }
    
    $Annonce->images = json_encode($data);
    $Annonce->save();

    return Redirect::to("annonces")
        ->withSuccess('Great! file has been successfully uploaded.');
    }
```

You can also use $casts property to let Laravel handle the casting of images attribute automatically

```php
class Annonce extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [ 'images' => 'array'];
}
```